# java assignment in string by using charAt()

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * @(#)wefeqwrf.java
 *
 * wefeqwrf application
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 1.00 2013/11/15
 */

public class wefeqwrf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO, add your application code
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);

        String number = "000";
        String a;

        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;a!="-1";i++)
        {   
            for(int k=0;k<3;k++){
                a=scan.next();

                a.charAt(0)= number.charAt(k);
            if(number.equals("110"))
            {
                System.out.print("Tebrikler!=110");
                count++;

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("Maalesef olmadı:" + number);
            }
            }


        }




    }
}
```

It gives the error:

```
error: unexpected type at this code: `a.charAt(0)= number.charAt(k);`
```

how can I assign the content of a to the specified index of number?

and when I changed the string a to the char a `scan.next()` does not work why and what can I do is there a any scanner method for char?

Comment: `String.charAt(int)` is a method that returns the VALUE of the character of the string at the specified point.  You can't assign it anything using this methodology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it this way:

```
a = number.charAt(k) + a.substring(1);
```

You can't assign something to a method. Methods only return something.